# counting numbers and allocating frequency in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code but it could not count the frequency of the divided elements but rather it kept on counting the index star for 100. How can I have  the frequency of the divided element.

```
public class Grade {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] grade = {87, 68, 94, 100, 83, 78, 85, 96, 76, 87};
    int[] frequency = new int[11];  

    for(int count=0; count< grade.length; count++) {
        int d1 = grade[count]/10;
         ++frequency[d1];
        for(int star=1; star<frequency.length; star++) {        
            System.out.printf("%4d%10d%n", star, frequency[star]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result for the star and frequency[star]

```
   1         -0,
   2        - 0,
   3       -  0,
   4      -   0,
   5     -    0,
   6    -     0,
   7   -      0,
   8  -       1,
   9 -        0,
  10-         0,

   1         -0,
   2        - 0,
   3       -  0,
   4      -   0,
   5     -    0,
   6    -     1,
   7   -      0,
   8  -       1,
   9 -        0,
  10-         0,

   1         -0,
   2        - 0,
   3       -  0,
   4      -   0,
   5     -    0,
   6    -     1,
   7   -      0,
   8  -       1,
   9 -        1,
  10-         0,

   1     -    0,
   2    -     0,
   3   -      0,
   4  -       0,
   5 -        0,
   6   -      1,
   7  -       0,
   8    -     1,
   9 -        1,
  10-         1,

   1         -0,
   2        - 0,
   3       -  0,
   4      -   0,
   5     -    0,
   6    -     1,
   7   -      0,
   8  -       2,
   9 -        1,
  10-         1,

   1         -0,
   2        - 0,
   3       -  0,
   4      -   0,
   5     -    0,
   6    -     1,
   7   -      1,
   8  -       2,
   9 -        1,
  10-         1,

   1        - 0,
   2         -0,
   3       -  0,
   4      -   0,
   5     -    0,
   6    -     1,
   7   -      1,
   8  -       3,
   9 -        1,
  10-         1,

   1       -  0,
   2        - 0,
   3       -  0,
   4      -   0,
   5     -    0,
   6    -     1,
   7   -      1,
   8  -       3,
   9 -        2,
  10-         1,

   1      -   0,
   2     -    0,
   3    -     0,
   4        - 0,
   5       -  0,
   6      -   1,
   7     -    2,
   8    -     3,
   9   -      2,
  10  -       1,

   1         -0,
   2        - 0,
   3       -  0,
   4      -   0,
   5     -    0,
   6        - 1,
   7       -  2,
   8       -  4,
   9      -   2,
  10     -    1,
```

Comment: This is unclear, can you provide what output you expect? Maybe the inner loop should be moved outside the outer one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have frequency of divided elements, but don't nest your loops.

first score is 87, first print of freq array has "8" element with a count of 1, all other elements are 0.  Second score is 67, second print of freq array has "6" with count of 1 and "8" with count of 1, all other elements are 0. and so on.

First loop through scores setting divided frequencies, then loop through frequencies and print once.

Comment: Thanks@geneSummons i can do in two ways i either open and close each loop or i do not close at all.I closed it and got my answer. thank you